# ksqlDB server shuts down when config, offset and status topic is changed

Tags: ksqldb

I'm running a single ksqlDB Server [on embedded mode](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.18.0-ksqldb/how-to-guides/use-connector-management/) on our Kubernetes cluster and I want to add a connector.

Adding a connector produces a `Request timed out on Kafka Connect` [exactly similar to this blog post by Robin Moffatt.](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/29/kafka-connect-request-timed-out/)

So he suggests to change the `KAFKA_OFFSET_REPLICATION_FACTOR` contained in his docker-compose example.

But unfortunately in our Test environment, I don't have easy access to the existing Kafka cluster (we have admins there), so I think the fastest way to go about is to instead change the:

- `KSQL_CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC` - change to a different topic name
- `KSQL_CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC`
- `KSQL_CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC`
- `KSQL_CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR` to `-1` (originally this value is 1)
- `KSQL_CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR` to `-1` (originally this value is 1)
- `KSQL_CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR` to `-1` (originally this value is 1)

But when I change the topic names, I can see that new topics are created (using ksqlDB's SHOW TOPICS command), but it always shuts down and restarts forever, here are the logs:

```
[2021-07-22 01:27:19,889] INFO ProcessingLogConfig values:
ksql.logging.processing.rows.include = false
ksql.logging.processing.stream.auto.create = false
ksql.logging.processing.stream.name = KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG
ksql.logging.processing.topic.auto.create = false
ksql.logging.processing.topic.name =
ksql.logging.processing.topic.partitions = 1
ksql.logging.processing.topic.replication.factor = 1


(io.confluent.ksql.logging.processing.ProcessingLogConfig:372)
[2021-07-22 01:27:19,891] ERROR Aborting application start (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication:378)
io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication$AbortApplicationStartException: Shutting down application during waitForPreconditions
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.waitForPreconditions(KsqlRestApplication.java:441)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.startKsql(KsqlRestApplication.java:386)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.startAsync(KsqlRestApplication.java:370)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.MultiExecutable.doAction(MultiExecutable.java:68)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.MultiExecutable.startAsync(MultiExecutable.java:42)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.tryStartApp(KsqlServerMain.java:89)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:64)
[2021-07-22 01:27:19,892] INFO Server up and running (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:90)
[2021-07-22 01:27:19,892] INFO Server shutting down (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:96)
[2021-07-22 01:27:19,892] INFO ksqlDB shutdown called (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication:498)
[2021-07-22 01:27:34,926] INFO API server stopped (io.confluent.ksql.api.server.Server:196)
[2021-07-22 01:27:34,927] INFO ksqlDB shutdown complete (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication:553)
```

I don't have anymore details, it's just that.

When I return the config, offset and status topic names to what I had at first, the ksqlDB Server starts fine, but again I'm stuck with the problem that I can't create connectors.

I have a fear that when I attempt to delete the topics manually, ksqlDB server wont be able to start properly because it keeps on finding the original config, offset and status topics I had at first.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, apparently using `-1` as value for:

- `KSQL_CONNECT_CONFIG_REPLICATION_FACTOR`
- `KSQL_CONNECT_OFFSET_REPLICATION_FACTOR`
- `KSQL_CONNECT_STATUS_REPLICATION_FACTOR`

doesn’t work properly, the Config topic becomes 20 partitions,

when I read in the Confluent Docs it should only be 1 partition, I think that’s why the ksqlDB Server just restarts endlessly, I just need to gather the right evidences.

Turning those values to `3` (which is our Kafka broker's default rep factor config) I think solved the issue, it was hard, because no error message/s are seen, like when it doesn’t want more than 1 partition of the created Config topic.

Comment: Replication factor `-1` means "use broker default" (assuming you have brokers that support this feature) -- what is your broker version?